# How to achieve a real copy like effect in printed page of Joplin notes?

Tags: html, css

I've edited the userstyle.css like this:

```css
/* For styling the rendered Markdown */

@media print {
    body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#1d97b8 0.05em, transparent 0.05em);
        line-height: 5rem;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        position: relative;
    }
    body::after {
        border-left: 6px solid green;
        height: 500px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 55px;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

It seems to be working on playcode.io for the horizontal lines. It's not working for the vertical lines though. As well as the line-height isn't changing even if I put 2rem or 10rem.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I've shown what I've tried above.

By real copy, I mean something like this:

https://codepen.io/amwill/pen/YyexrJ

More samples here:

https://devsnap.me/css-paper-effect

Update: Real working scenario snippet:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1d97b8 0.05em, transparent 0.05em);
  line-height: 5rem;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  position: relative;
}
body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 45px;
  height: 100%;
  width:20px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 106, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, not just a snippet of CSS that lacks context.

Comment: The lines in that example are created by the background repeating gradient, they are not actually tied to the text, so `line-height` will have no effect. But you could update the `background-image` to affect the height of those lines (Perhaps even use a CSS variable to keep it in sync with `line-height`)

Comment: @DBS how do I do that? Any commands you know?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the background image to match your line height.

This approach uses [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to keep the two in sync, building a linear gradient that matches the height.

The only complex part of this is the background image rule, which I'll break down here:

```css
background-image: 
  repeating-linear-gradient(
    /* Start with a block of white from 0 */
    #fff 0px, 
    /* to the desired line height - 1px */
    #fff calc(var(--line-height) - 1px), 
    /* Fill the final 1px with the colour that will be our line */
    #1d97b8 var(--line-height) 
  );
```

Working example (You can adjust the `--line-height` variable, and everything else should work as-is):

```css
:root {
  /* Define our CSS variable */
  --line-height: 25px;
}

body {
  /* Create the lined background */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#fff 0px, #fff  calc(var(--line-height) - 1px), #1d97b8 var(--line-height));
  /* Apply a line height to the text */
  line-height: var(--line-height);
  /* Cover the entire page */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* The default margin would offset the text, but not the background image */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

A simpler version with hard-coded heights:

```css
body {
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#fff 0px, #fff 24px, #1d97b8 25px);
  line-height: 25px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: @media print{


* {
 /* Create the lined background */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(#fff 0px, #fff  calc(25px - 1px), #1d97b8 25px);
  /* Apply a line height to the text */
  line-height:25px;
  /* Cover the entire page */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* The default margin would offset the text, but not the background image */
  margin: 0;
}
}

Comment: I tried this code, doesn't work on joplin.

Comment: @achhainsan I've added a simpler version at the bottom (hidden by default, click to expand it) that may work better if "joplin" doesn't support some of the modern CSS being used in the original version.

Comment: the code works(I'd to restart the computer) BUT problem is the words aren't being synced with letters. Is there an easy css hack for it. Problem: https://imgur.com/a/T5qgRW0

Comment: The approach you were copying relies on all of the text/inline elements being the same (vertical) size. I'm not sure how it would be expected to look in a scenario where you have multiple line heights, isn't this trying to emulate lined paper?

Comment: yes I'm trying to emulate lined papers. i don't think it can get better than this. thanks for the support. I'm decently happy with what I've got now.